# Как сверстать треугольный элемент с помощью псевдоэлемента?

Tags: вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сверстать треугольный элемент, с правой стороны хэдера? Нужно чтобы он был под шапкой. Свойство `z-index` не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: шапке надо задать position: relative и (если понадобится) тоже какой-нибудь z-index - выше, чем у треугольника

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы поместить потомка шапки под неё, можно задать ему(потомку) отрицательный `z-index` или ещё одному потомку шапки задать `position:relative` и `z-index` больше, чем у треугольника.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  background-color:#cda;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
}
header{
  height:60px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  border-radius:6px;
  position:relative;
}
header:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  right:-10px;
  top:-10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:linear-gradient(225deg,red 50%,transparent 50%);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Вариант 2

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  background-color:#cda;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
}
header{
  position:relative;
}
.header-inner{
  height:60px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  border-radius:6px;
  position:relative;
}
header:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  right:-10px;
  top:-10px;
  border-top:100px solid red;
  border-left:100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<header><div class="header-inner"></div></header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, рисуете квадрат, а к нему:

-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);

clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);

Answer (score 0):

[Треугольники через CSS](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/treugolniki-cherez-css), для позиционирования задайте для навигации больше `z-index` и `position: relative;`